# menu inline menu float left with width and height to % on pure css

Tags: html, css

```
#headermenu ul li {
    width:195px;
    height:45px;
    float:left;
    left:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:century gothic;
    background-color:#fef3e2;
}
```

this is my li css ive been trying to make the width and height to a certain percent but apparently its not working..my question is, is there a way or is it possible to set this width and height to percent i dont want to use table here because if i do the submenu when hover in the menu will be distorted meaning they will be side by side not on top of each other(i want them to be on top of each other)..any idea is appreciated..

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/gvmRX/

in this fidde you can see that i change the li size to 100 to make it fit in the this is the reason why i want to make it a percent width if possible to avoid over sized width

Comment: Pls create a fiddle ? OR Add your HTML Part as well.

Comment: @VaibhavJain wait i will work on a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to give a `height` and `width` in a percentage you need to give the parent the `width` and `height`.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul li {
    width: 33%;
    height: 33%;
    float:left;
    left:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:century gothic;
    background-color:#fef3e2;
}
```

In this demo we have the `<li>` you can see it is using a width as percentage as the parent has already a set width (`<ul>` is a block element) but the height is not set already so the percentage height it not working.

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9f7aJ/)

Now lets set the parents height and see if it changes anything.

**Added CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

ul {
    height: 100%;
}
```

so here we are setting the `html, body` height to use 100% and then the the parent of `<li>` needs to also be set (again `<ul>` is a block element, so it has no set height). This allows us to use percentages for the height.

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9f7aJ/1/)

Any question let me know.

Comment: i have a question but i will try to uncover this as well might as well as it...based on my fiddle there above why this the submenu of submenu width became small i just added the 100% width and height it works but there is a side effect..

Comment: i think the 20% width is used as the width of that submenu so i became so small..what do you think?do you have idea

Comment: @HakHak That didn't make a lot of sense to me, could you try explaining what exactly is wrong with it and how you would like it to look etc.

Comment: i tried your solution it worked..so here is the scenario..i hover the menu it dropsdown a menu all is ok then i hover on the dropdown menu the submenu's width is very small..maybe the submenu of dropdown is using the 20% width of the dropdown that is why it is so small i am not sure but im guessing this is happening im still researching to fix or to know if im correct..check this fiddle for more details http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/gvmRX/3/

Comment: @HakHak I think I understand but for me the submenu's are all the same width. 100px as thats is what you have set them to. The sub sub menu are using the same with as there parent. Oh this fiddle is what is happening. Ok for it, let me have a look.

Comment: @HakHak Right, I think you are correct. It was setting as 20% width, we need to define the sub sub menus width because of the way you have done it. So adding `#headermenu ul ul ul li { width: 100%; }` should fix the problem. [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gvmRX/5/)

Comment: i have i more question regarding the last menu #headermenu ul ul ul:last-child{
 position: absolute; 
 right: 100%; 
 top:0;
}

to show the submenu of dropdown to right but its not working only for the last child

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57746/discussion-between-ruddy-and-hak-hak).